# Dynamic View in Android

Tags: java, c#, android, android-view, dynamic-view

I have a file of code in `c#`, `c#` is more like java. Is there any way I can add an `edittext` or a `button` or a `spinner` from a server to app? and not from `XML` or `java`(`c#` `.cs` file). I want it in such a way that when my web administrator stays remotely to update the app and if he desires a few more `spinners`, `edittext` or `buttons` then he should be able to do so without me actually re-coding the app from my end. this is my `.cs` file so far. But JAVA (ANDROID) is fine with me.

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Content.Res;
using Android.Util;

namespace EditDynamics
{
    [Activity(Label = "EditDynamics", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        RelativeLayout rl;


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            // SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it

            rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
            rl.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.CadetBlue);
            //rl.CanScrollVertically();

            Spinner sp = new Spinner(this);
            EditText et1 = new EditText(this);
            EditText et2 = new EditText(this);
            EditText et3 = new EditText(this);
            EditText et4 = new EditText(this);
            EditText et5 = new EditText(this);
            TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
            Button bt1 = new Button(this);

            tv1.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.DarkRed);
            et1.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
            et2.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
            et3.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
            et4.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
            et5.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);

            //Set Text on Button
            bt1.Text = "Send Me";


            //setting Id Programatically
            sp.Id = 1; et1.Id = 2; et2.Id = 3; et3.Id = 4; et4.Id = 5; tv1.Id = 6; bt1.Id = 7;


            /* a layout view is typically created by declaring how
            the view should be sized in relation to the parent view */


            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams et1Params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
         //   et1Params.TopMargin = 50;

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams et2Params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
          //  et2Params.TopMargin = 100;


            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams et3Params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
         //   et3Params.TopMargin = 150;

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams et4Params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
         //   et4Params.TopMargin = 200;

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams et5Params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
         //   et5Params.TopMargin = 250;

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tv1Params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
          //  tv1Params.TopMargin = 400;

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams btParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);

            //setting the properties of the layout params

            btParams.LeftMargin = 100;
            btParams.RightMargin = 100;
            et1Params.AddRule(LayoutRules.Above);
            et1Params.AddRule(LayoutRules.CenterHorizontal);
            et1Params.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 40);


            et2Params.AddRule(LayoutRules.Below, et1.Id);
            et2Params.AddRule(LayoutRules.CenterHorizontal);
            et2Params.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 40);

            et3Params.AddRule(LayoutRules.Below, et2.Id);
            et3Params.AddRule(LayoutRules.CenterHorizontal);
            et3Params.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 40);

            et4Params.AddRule(LayoutRules.Below, et3.Id);
            et4Params.AddRule(LayoutRules.CenterHorizontal);
            et4Params.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 40);

            et5Params.AddRule(LayoutRules.Below, et4.Id);
            et5Params.AddRule(LayoutRules.CenterHorizontal);
            et5Params.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 40);

            tv1Params.AddRule(LayoutRules.Below, et4.Id);
            tv1Params.AddRule(LayoutRules.CenterHorizontal);
            tv1Params.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 150);

            btParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.Below, tv1.Id);
            btParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.CenterHorizontal);
            btParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.CenterVertical);


            //convert de to px for edittext
            Resources r = Resources;
            int px = (int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip,
                     200,
                r.DisplayMetrics);

            et1.SetWidth(px);
            et2.SetWidth(px);
            et3.SetWidth(px);
            et4.SetWidth(px);
            et5.SetWidth(px);




            rl.AddView(et1, et1Params);
            rl.AddView(et2, et2Params);
            rl.AddView(et3, et3Params);
            rl.AddView(et4, et4Params);
            rl.AddView(et5, et5Params);
            rl.AddView(tv1, tv1Params);
            rl.AddView(bt1, btParams);
            SetContentView(rl);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd have to create an app that parses a message from the server and based on that builds some sort of `View` hierarchy. But tbh that would be a huge pain in the butt to write.

Comment: sure it will be but I guess theres a way out. Thanks @Bartek